# Squared Series Fourier

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, problem-solving

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fourier 1st step?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160051/fourier-1st-step)

How to  find fourier transform of a series of the such form:
$$y_k=\left[f(x) \right]^{2},$$
but I am not sure of the step by step for going about this computation.

how is the first step??

thank you very much!!

Comment: What is $k$?  You don't take Fourier transform of a series.

Comment: to be specfic, it states $y_{k} = [k-\frac{n-1}{2}]^{2}$ thank you very much!!

Comment: Wait, where is $x$ in that definition of $y_k$?

Comment: my error. the true problem is stated with $y_K$ and i wrote question as f(x)...does this answer? i am really lost here!! how do you know when to use integral vs when to use sum to find the transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration by parts.  You're doing an integral of the form
$$ \int (f(x))^2 \exp(i\xi x) dx $$

Let $u = (f(x))^2$ and $dv = \exp(i \xi x)$.

Comment: Based on nanme's comment and previous question, I find it likely OP means the discrete transform.

Comment: i think so too!but how to go about this?